# How to select key value [object:object] in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to take pincode from filtered data from object.
and i want to display in HTML select in angular

```
[ { 
"stateName": "UP", 
"stateCode": "2", 
"pincode": [ { "pin": 555, "dis": "Gazhipur" }, 
         { "pin": 888, "dis": "Agra" } 
       ] 
} ]
```

i expect for html select

```
{
   "pincode": [ 
                {"pin": 555, "dis": "Gazhipur" }, 
                {"pin": 888, "dis": "Agra" } 
              ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.assign()` and manipulate the data as shown below.

```js
const data = [ { 
"stateName": "UP", 
"stateCode": "2", 
"pincode": [ { "pin": 555, "dis": "Gazhipur" }, 
         { "pin": 888, "dis": "Agra" } 
       ] 
} ];

const result = data[0].pincode;
const expectedResult = Object.assign({}, {"pincode": result});

console.log(expectedResult);
```

Your `html` should look like this.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of expectedResult.pincode"
  <span>{{item.pin}}: {{item.dis}}</span> {{hero.name}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array of objects like this code and put the result in the select

```
let result = states.map(state => {
    return state.pincode
})
// or
let result = states.map(state => state.pincode)
```